# Sort javascript objects based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript

The `dataSet` contains arrays of javascript objects. Each object  has the property `color` and `weight`. I am able sort the data based on the `color`. However I would like to know how to sort and combine data based on `color` and `weight` together and then push data to `an`

In other words, let say I have two arrays of javascript objects. I would like to find the pair of these objects  `(color, weight)`  in all dataSet then push.

**Input:**

```
dataSet[0].data= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow", weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow", weight:12}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red", weight:13}
];          
dataSet[1].data= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow", weight:12}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:11}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:11}
];
colorMap=["red","green","blue","yellow","pink","black"];
```

**Current output:**

```
an[0]=[
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
]
an[1]=[{color:"red",weight:13},{color:"red",weight:13}]
an[2]=[{color:"yellow",weight:12},{color:"yellow",weight:12}]
an[3]=[{color:"red",weight:13},{color:"red",weight:13}]
an[4]=[{color:"blue",weight:11},{color:"blue",weight:11}]
```

**Desired output:**

```
an[0]=[
   {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
]
an[1]=[
    {color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
]
an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:11},{color:"blue",weight:11}]
```

Here is my current implementation

```
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < self.colorMap.length; j++) {
      var d = dataSet[i].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == self.colorMap[j] });
        if (d.length > 0) {
        an.push({ data: d, color: d[0].color, name:d[0].weight.toString()});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code correctly?

Comment: I read this question 5 times already and I still do not understand it. Sorry.

Comment: What is that `colorMap` in the code block? What is the `dataSet` you have? What is `an`?

Comment: Does `{yellow,12}` mean `{yellow:12}` or `[yellow,12]` or `{color:yellow, weight:12}`?

Comment: The first is `color`, the second is `weight`. {color:yellow, weight:12}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use underscore you can use the groupBy function to help you here. Otherwise you can define groupBy yourself.

```
function groupBy(arr, f) {
  var result = {};
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    var fElem = f(elem),
        list = result[fElem] || [];
    list.push(elem);
    result[fElem] = list;
  });
  return result;
}

function objToArray(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for(k in obj) {
    result.push(obj[k]);
  }
  return result;
}

var dataSet = [];
dataSet[0]= [{color:"yellow",weight:12},{color:"yellow", weight:12},{color:"yellow", weight:12},{color:"red",weight:13},{color:"red", weight:13}];
dataSet[1]= [{color:"yellow",weight:12},{color:"yellow", weight:12},{color:"red",weight:13},{color:"red",weight:13},{color:"blue",weight:11},{color:"blue",weight:11}];


var allData = dataSet.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b) });
var grouped = objToArray(groupBy(allData, function(data) { return data.color + "#" + data.weight }));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: btw. does the same color always have the same weight?

Comment: Yes, same color has always same weight.